# RTCMultiConnection signaling server config with existing socket-io server

Tags: webrtc

Me try to config RTCMultiConnection  signaling server  with existing socket-io server but any luck.Me also try with namespace.

Please provide solution,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in your nodejs file:

```
require('./Signaling-Server.js')(socket);
```

Now modify [Signaling-Server.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/Signaling-Server.js)

```
module.exports = exports = function(socket, socketCallback) {
};
```

Now you're expecting `socket` rather than `app` object. Parameters are changed.

Now remove these lines:

```
io = io(app);
```

as well as:

```
// otherwise fallback
io = io.listen(app, {
    log: false,
    origins: '*:*'
});

io.set('transports', [
    'websocket',
    'xhr-polling',
    'jsonp-polling'
]);
```

Now `Signaling-Server.js` will use your existing socket object.

You can remove `io.on('connection', onConnection)` as well. Now you need to manually call `onConnection` method. Call it at the bottom of `Signaling-Server.js`:

```
onConnection(socket); // bottom of the file (before closing braces)
```

---

Please check this pastebin for the modified `Signaling-Server.js`. You simply need to copy and replace the code: https://pastebin.com/GdKdNvHH

Comment: Thanks for ans. Please provide a solution when we have already socket-io chat application and we have to config RTCMultiConnection both in server and client side. Thanks in advance.